# Android Jetpack Compose - Dynamic layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

**Background**

I'm currently investigating options for creating layouts, during the development of the project I'm looking to possibly migrate the UI to Jetpack Compose or post release, depending on the stability/flexibility of the library.

Part of the project will be using a server driven UI.  However the twist being the UI is not known ahead of time and will be dynamic (server and data driven).

I have no issues with handling the business logic and presentation layers however when it comes to the UI I will need a requirement to dynamically build the UI based on the presentation data and view models.

**TL;DR**

With this in mind is it possible to create dynamic layouts (not to be confused with dynamic layout data) using Jetpack Compose?

As a minimal example, with traditional `View` and `ViewGroup` this can easily be achieved :

```
class DynamicViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var root : LinearLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        // setup view group container
        root = LinearLayout(this)
        root.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        root.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        
        setContentView(root, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
        
        // some lookup to create a dynamic layout
        val children : List<Pair<View, LinearLayout.LayoutParams>> = getChildren(someArgs)
        
        // add child views
        children.forEach { (view, params) -> root.addView(view, params) }
    }
    
    fun <T : View> addViewToRoot(view: T, params: LinearLayout.LayoutParams) {
        root.addView(view, params)
    }

    fun  removeFromRoot(viewTag : String) {
        root.findViewWithTag<View>(viewTag)?.let(root::removeView)
    }
}
```

How do you do the same with Jetpack Compose?

**Update**

Following the answer from @CommonsWare I implemented the UI in Compose.  As my actual code has a very thin UI layer, with all listeners and events using one and two-way data binding, and "unknowns" in the answer already addressed in my project it was incredibly easy to just swap the UI over.

Having said that I soon realised that simple things like `ScrollView` and `View::tooltipText` do not yet exist in Compose.  Also there is no easy way to have layouts based on runtime configuration (screen orientation / screen bucket size etc) in comparison to xml layouts/resources.  This means for me, using data binding with all the rich `View` framework and libraries is still the better solution.

Looking forward to Compose library updates and maybe look at some point in the future.

Comment: Um, replace the vertical `LinearLayout` with a `Column()`, and replace `getChildren()` with calls to composables. IOW, at the level of your example, there is very little to do, because you hide all the complexity in `getChildren(someArgs)`.

Comment: I have never used compose before. This might be a basic question for my usecase.  After nearly a week of no comments/answers/upvotes/downvotes I decided to take a punt to open a bounty.  I guess its either apathy, limited community compose exposure or a poorly asked question possibly. I'll have a look into your suggestion thanks.

Comment: "I have never used compose before" -- in the end, Compose is all functions. As such, if anything, server-defined UI is easier, because you're not dealing with inflating layouts or dealing with funky assembly of widgets and containers. With server-defined UI, you just happen to be calling functions based on what you get from a server.

Comment: sure, I get that in fact I'm hooking into a closed source framework that uses vue.js
under the hood.  With no exposure to declarative UI's and Compose I'm asking, what are to me, logical questions about what it takes to create just-in-time UI's with compose.  All examples I've seen to "dip my toe in" are all known UI's ahead of time - I have to deal with online/offline as well just as a curve ball. I have some ideas to create some sort of factory pattern after your hint, to return higher order functions, which are the composables to just invoke, not sure if that possible but I'll give it a go

Comment: "I'm asking, what are to me, logical questions about what it takes to create just-in-time UI's with compose" -- your end question ("How do you do the same with Jetpack Compose?") is tied to a code sample that has nothing obvious to do with server-defined UIs. For example, you could have a sample that shows a `when` branching to different UI construction paths based upon some server-supplied object, where those paths construct views. Somebody could then show you a `when` branching to different UI construction paths based upon some server-supplied object, where those paths call composables.

Comment: "I get that in fact I'm hooking into a closed source framework that uses vue.js under the hood" -- Jetpack Compose is open source and is not based on JavaScript. I suppose that Compose for Web could be using vue.js, though that would surprise me. [This post](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/jetpack-compose-with-server-driven-ui-396a19f0a661), [this post](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/server-driven-ui-for-android-with-jetpack-compose-6763ec60f33e), and [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE9ZE0DzLFs) discuss server-defined UI with Compose, though they may be a bit old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> With this in mind is it possible to create dynamic layouts (not to be confused with dynamic layout data) using Jetpack Compose?

Sure. Compose is all functions. You can parse data and call functions based on that data, whether that data is "fill in this pre-defined UI structure" or that data is "define the UI structure".

For example, suppose your server has an endpoint that returns the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "element": "label",
    "attributes": {
      // values omitted for brevity
    }
  },
  {
    "element": "field",
    "attributes": {
      // values omitted for brevity
    }
  },
  // additional elements omitted for brevity
]
```

Your job is to assemble a UI based on that JSON. A `label` element should be fixed text, a `field` element should be a text entry field, and so on for various types. The `attributes` object contains details that vary by element.

So, you parse that. Suppose that you wind up with a `List<UiElement>` as a result, where `UiElement` is an interface or abstract class or something, with sub-types based upon the supported elements (e.g., `LabelElement`, `FieldElement`). Now your job is to construct a UI based on that `List<UiElement>`.

---

In `View`-space, you could have a function that creates a `View` based on a supplied `UiElement`:

```kotlin
fun buildView(element: UiElement) = when (element) {
    is LabelElement -> buildTextView(element)
    is FieldElement -> buildEditText(element)
    else -> TODO("add other element cases here")
}
```

`buildTextView()` would assemble a `TextView`, whether inflating from a layout or calling a constructor. `buildEditText()` would assemble an `EditText`, whether inflating from a layout or calling a constructor. And so on. Each of those functions would be responsible for grabbing values out of the `attributes` and doing something useful with them, such as setting the text in a `TextView` or the hint in an `EditText`.

In the code snippet in your question, rather than your `getChildren()`-and-loop approach, you would iterate over the `List<UiElement>` and call `buildView()` for each `UiElement` in the list, and adding the result to your `LinearLayout`.

---

The Compose equivalent would be something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun buildNode(element: UiElement) {
    when (element) {
        is LabelElement -> buildTextNode(element)
        is FieldElement -> buildTextFieldNode(element)
        else -> TODO("add other element cases here")
    }
}
```

IOW, it would be nearly identical. The key differences are:

- the `@Composable` annotation (also required on `buildTextNode()` and `buildTextFieldNode()`)
- no need to return anything, as composables are added automatically to the parent
- the details of what goes in `buildTextNode()` and `buildTextFieldNode()` would be reminiscent of `buildTextView()` and `buildEditText()`, but based on composables

Your activity would have something like this:

```kotlin
Column {
    uiElements.forEach { buildNode(it) }
}
```

...as a replacement for your `LinearLayout`.

(in reality, both examples would need a scrolling container, but we'll ignore that here as well)

---

All of the complexity of server-defined UI lies outside of the scope of your code sample:

- How do I parse the server response?
- How do I map that server response into an object model representing the desired UI?
- How do I get my per-element UI bits to work?
- How do I handle event listeners?
- More generally, what are we doing in response to user input on this UI?
- How will we re-generate this UI as needed (for views, based on configuration changes; for composables, based on recomposition)?
- And so on

Some of that will be identical between a `View`-based UI and a Compose-based UI — JSON parsing, for example. Some of that will be substantially different, such as handling user input.

But the general approach of "parse the server response and create UI elements based on that response", views and composables are equally up to the challenge. In particular, at the level of the code sample in your question, views and composables can both handle your high-level scenario. The devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. All the "outside" scope I already do, in fact I was doing everything using data binding, inflating individual widgets - the only piece of the puzzle was the Compose basics.

Comment: To piggy back off of this excellent answer consider using Kotlin Flows or LiveData to respond to state automatically when data is updated from the server.

Comment: Right now I have a similar problem. I am thinking to use the Visitor pattern to build the different types of layouts